# Fetch Facebook Friends List with Android SDK is not returning values in Facebook Friends Picker Sample

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I did try to use the sample provided by Facebook - HelloFacebookSample & FriendPickerSample but its not giving any list of friends.

Are there any specific permissions I have to provide in app or we have do certain provisions in application created on Facebook.

Comment: In API v2.0 and later you will only see friends that are also using the app

Comment: That will also be OK to me if I can see who has logged in my application using Facebook. But I couldn't get those friends also. 

Few days back, I created one app_id and used that in demo app provided with Android SDK. I am using "HelloFacebookSample" provided there where I could see those 2 users as friends of each other in that app when I logged in into that application.

Comment: Those 2 users are also friends of each other so those are returned in that list. Now when I have 3rd user using the same application and he is mutual friend of these 2 users, he should also be in a list, but he himself neither show those 2 users as friend on his phone not those 2 users show him as a friend in same app.